# How does VSCode access the filesystem?

Tags: visual-studio-code, server, client, file-system-access-api

Is there a client/server architecture present in VSCode, with a Node server running in the background providing file access? Or do they use the File System Access API?

Comment: On the Web, `https://vscode.dev/` uses the File System Access API.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably figured this out already, since the question is from a few months ago, but:

Vscode is created in electron, which runs a web browser inside of it to render the onscreen elements which are created in html. however, the file system access api is only for websites, and requires special permissions on account of the fact that any website shouldn't be allowed access to your files unless explicitly asked. Because of this, electron apps are half programmed in node, which has low level access to your hardware. To access the filesystem, it uses `require('fs')` library syntax, which lets you control files more freely. fs library in node gains its filesystem access from your OS's native fs libraries, which requires user confirmation depending on how much access you want.